# what the keyword for formula in excel

Tags: excel

[image: Table]

https://indocropcircles.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/tabel-kecocokan-plasma-darah.png

I want to make a call if I fill in "Type Blood" so the Blood Type will come out which is suitable for the type of blood I entered And information will come out why I got a suitable blood recommendation for that. so the results can be two. as in the table.

[image: Enter Type Blood]

> Type Your Blood :
>
> The Blood Match :
>
> Information :

but I don't know how to make a formula for that. I want to do it in Excel.

logically like this:
If I enter Type A, the Type of blood that matches  is AB and O will come out; otherwise, it is not suitable no need to show

Type A = AB & O

Type B = AB & O

Type AB = B & A

Type O = A & B

Comment: I don't see how this is a bad question and/or too broad :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use `VLOOKUP`. You specifiy a table (cell range) which contains your mapping and refer to it.

[image]

[Source](https://exceljet.net/formula/map-inputs-to-arbitrary-values)

Comment: oh great! it works. thanks. I'm just confused what if I put out two results? A and/or B

Comment: just put the two values in one cell. so in your Output column (from example) would be "AB & 0", below "AB & 0" and so on....